# Prestashop hookActionCartSave function run 2 times?

Tags: prestashop

I created a presta module and use the actionCartSave hook.
But when I print string in hookActionCartSave function, it display double result
I dont know why, can you explain for me that?

My code:

```
    public function hookActionCartSave()
    {
        if (!$this->active || !Validate::isLoadedObject($this->context->cart) || !Tools::getIsset('id_product')) return;

        print_r('expression');
    }
```

The result is:

```
    expressionexpression
```

Thank you

Comment: The cart is saved more of one time during the navigation, so the the hook is called more of one time :)

Comment: Can I run it 1 time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook `ActionCartSave` is called in `add` and `update` method of `Cart` class.

```
public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = false)
{
    /* ... */
    Hook::exec('actionCartSave');

    return $return;
}
```

```
public function update($null_values = false)
{
    /* ... */
    Hook::exec('actionCartSave');

    return $return;
}
```

So if you search in various controller you discover that the cart is saved more times, so the hook is called more of one times :)

Comment: How can I run it one time (only)?

Comment: I create a variable and set status again, seems it can working fine. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for late answer, you can't run it one time because it's out of your control :). I'm glad to hear that you have found a solution, you're welcome ;)

Comment: Hello @phinq.  I need to limit the execution of this hook too. What's the workaround you found to solve this ? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I found a workaround. I use the `actionObjectCartUpdateAfter` hook instead of the `ActionCartSave` hook.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Its same.